# Easy code troubleshooting in wordpress

Tags: debug, troubleshooting

Is there an easy and standard way to debug our code in wordpress plugins?
I want to print some variables in a function that runs when a certain things happen. 
Is there a wordpress way to save this in a file or at least see it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to troubleshoot/debug your PHP code for WordPress is to use the [XDEBUG](https://xdebug.org/) debugger for PHP coupled with an IDE/editor that can leverage XDEBUG.

By far my favorite IDE for PHP/XDEBUG is [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) *(best money I have ever spent)*, but you can use for free on the bleeding edge with [their EAP *(Early Access Program)*](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/eap/). You can also use the free [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with XDEBUG.

Here is a [**great video showing**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GokeXqI93x8) what it looks like to use XDEBUG & PhpStorm. You can start at the `18:00` point because everything before that is talking and slides.

You will also need a local development setup that supports XDEBUG. Several years ago I was frustrated with how difficult it was to get XDEBUG configured correctly so I had my team develop [WPLib Box](https://wplib.org/box) which pre-configures XDEBUG and thus makes using XDEBUG trivally easy. You can [download](https://github.com/wplib/wplib-box/releases) WPLib Box from GitHub, use for free, and get help via [our Slack](https://launchpass.com/wplib).

I like to say using PhpStorm/XDEBUG/WPlib Box gives me WordPress superpowers. How else do you think I answered all the questions here at WPSE that I have? :-)

That said, there are also other local development solutions such as [VVV](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV), [Trellis](https://roots.io/trellis/), [Chassis](https://github.com/Chassis/Chassis), [Desktop Server](https://serverpress.com), [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/), [DevilBox](https://github.com/devilbox/devilbox.org), [LaraDock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock), [Kalabox](https://github.com/kalabox/kalabox), [Kusanagi](https://en.kusanagi.tokyo/) and others you might try. But I am not sure how difficult it is to set up XDEBUG to work with any of these others anymore but I know firsthand XDEBUG works without any fuss when using WPLib Box.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just start with the following definitions in your config.php file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

The first one sets your system into debug mode, the second one writes every notice into a log file saved into your `wp-content` directory. Script debug enables WordPress to use the uncompressed CSS and JS files (Maybe also interesting for writing Plugins). And Savequeries writes HTML-Comments at the bottom of the rendered HTML Output and will be used by Plugins I suggest you next.

See the WordPress Plugin Directory for [Debug Bar and extensions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/debug+bar/). There are a lot and there's a great chance that some of them are providing exactly what you need.

If nothing helps you can write everytime

```
print_r( $var );
die();
```

and look into the HTML sourcecode.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't really a standard developer logging API in WordPress. If you want to output your own data to a debug file (to prevent "headers already sent" errors) then you can simply use the standard PHP `error_log` function. Something simple like this will record the variable `$data` to the file `debug.log` in your plugins directory:

```
$debugline = '['.date('y m d H:i:s', time()).'] '.print_r($data,true);
$debugfilepath = dirname(__FILE__).'/debug.log';
error_log($debugline, 3, $debugfilepath);
```